# formula to see if a surname is repeated within a cell and output a simplified string

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, excel-2003, vba

I have a list of several thousand items, which consist of several different names together like this:

```
Mr P Thompson & Mrs S Thompson & Mr A Thompson
Mr C Guy-Johnson & Mrs A Guye-Johnson & Miss J Guye-Johnson
Mrs Fuller & Ms D Fuller & Dr K U Fuller
Dr V Patel & Dr OO Patel
Mr B Burden & Mr MP Wood & Ms C Pollock
Mr PW Philips & Mrs PW Philips
Dr D Watson & S Holmes
Mr R Polanski & Mrs S Polanski
Mr S Spielberg & Miss G Spielberg & Mrs T Spielberg
```

Sometimes the surname is repeated within the cell, sometimes it is not.

I want to build a formula that will determine if the surname is repeated, and return a string where the Salutations/titles and inititals are concatenated with the Surname at the end, unless the surnames are different.

For example,

```
- Mr S Spielberg & Miss G Spielberg & Mrs T Spielberg
- Mr R Polanski & Mrs S Polanski
```

would become,

```
- Mr S & Miss G & Mrs T Spielberg
- Mr R & Mrs S Polanski
```

BUT:

```
- Mr B Burden & Mr MP Wood & Ms C Pollock
- Dr D Watson & S Holmes
```

would remain the same as the surnames are different

Is it possible to do that with formulas, (and not splitting the names using Text to Columns), and how would I do that please?

thanks
Philip

Comment: Would there be a case like this? `Mr S Spielberg & Ms C Pollock & Mrs T Spielberg` ?

Comment: yes, it could be, but in that case Spielberg would only appear once in the output... as we can assume the two are from the same family

Comment: BTW, I replied to your comment on my Find question, wherte would I send the file please?

Comment: Hmmm, that makes it complex. And you are not open to VBA or UDF?

Comment: any solution would be great at this stage with my boss breathing down my neck, but was hoping for a formula...

Comment: `but was hoping for a formula...` I guess Barry or Lori would be able to come up with a smart formula. :)

Comment: You want it to be a single formula or can it be a set of formulas as well per line?

Comment: @K_B - ideally one formula, but I am not wedded to the idea, any solution that produces reliable results would be great...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure Barry or Lori would come up with a smart formula :) However here is a VBA example which might just solve your boss's `breathing` problem ;)

Paste this code in a module. (*Tested only with the samples in the screenshot below*). I took the liberty to manipulate one of the cell values to take into consideration multiple matches in surnames. See Cell `A1`

```
Function GetNewNames(rng As Range) As String
    Dim MyAr() As String, tmpAr() As String
    Dim prevValue As String, sTmp As String, surName As String, sTemp As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim itm As Variant

    On Error GoTo Whoa:

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        prevValue = rng.Value

        If InStr(1, prevValue, "&") Then
            MyAr = Split(prevValue, "&")

            For i = 0 To UBound(MyAr)
                sTmp = Trim(MyAr(i))
                If InStr(1, sTmp, " ") Then
                    tmpAr = Split(sTmp, " ")
                    surName = tmpAr(UBound(tmpAr))
                Else
                    surName = sTmp
                End If

                On Error Resume Next
                col.Add surName, Chr(34) & surName & Chr(34)
                On Error Resume Next
            Next i

            For Each itm In col
                For i = 0 To UBound(MyAr)
                    sTmp = Trim(MyAr(i))

                    If InStr(1, sTmp, " ") Then
                        tmpAr = Split(sTmp, " ")
                        surName = tmpAr(UBound(tmpAr))
                    Else
                        surName = sTmp
                    End If

                    If surName = itm Then
                        If sTemp = "" Then
                            sTemp = Trim(MyAr(i))
                        Else
                            sTemp = Replace(sTemp & " & " & Trim(MyAr(i)), itm & " &", "&")
                        End If
                    End If
                Next i
            Next

            GetNewNames = sTemp
        Else
            GetNewNames = prevValue
        End If
    End If
    Exit Function
Whoa:
    GetNewNames = ""
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this task over the past week I found a use for this excellent formula by Mr Excel MVP **Aladin Akyurek** [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/61485-counting-spaces.html#post287792) which counts how many spaces are in a cell (used it to decide whether initials were needed as if no Salutaion or first name, only surname is used)

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
```

On [Ozgrid Forums](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=178202&p=662998#post662998) **Jindon** came up with this Regex solution which gives me yet more encouragement to hit my O'Reilly *Regular Expressions Cookbook* again:

```
Sub test() 
    Dim r As Range, txt 
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 
        .Pattern = "(.* )?(\S{3,})( .* )(\2)( .*)?" 
        For Each r In Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 
            txt = r 
            Do While .test(txt) 
                txt = .Replace(txt, "$1$3$4$5") 
            Loop 
            r(, 2) = Application.Trim(txt) 
        Next 
    End With 
End Sub
```

and on [VBA Express forums](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showpost.php?p=290015&postcount=5) **SNB** came up with this **lovely array CSE formula**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,MAX((MID(A1,ROW(1:100),1)=" ")*ROW(1:100)),100),"")&MID(A1,MAX((MID(A1,ROW(1:100),1)=" ")*ROW(1:100)),100)
```

also on [VBA Express forums](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showpost.php?p=290015&postcount=5) **mdmackillop** came up with this lovely bit of clever thinking:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",50)),50))," ") & TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",50)),50))
```

which I modified and used as below:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(W:W,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(W:W)," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)) & " ","")
```

also on [Mr Excel Forums](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/700525-count-how-many-times-word-repeated-within-cell-build-new-simplified-name-strings.html#post3461076) **Gerald Higgins** proposed this which I found quite entertaining trying to break down and decode:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("ZZZ",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","ZZZ",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))),"")&" "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("ZZZ",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","ZZZ",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))
```

(but I had already handed in my work to my manager so had already made use of Sid's solution)