# Is there way to find duplicate words?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm trying to find/make a program that will find all my duplicate words in Excel. For example in A1 "someone" in A2 ""person" and etc but I'll have "someone" multiples times or another word and I need to condense that information together. But I need to do it in a way where I don't search manually to concatenate duplicates. So is there a way to find the duplicate words and concatenate them?

I have also been looking into doing it using "FIND" to look for them but it has yielded no luck yet. I also have been using the "FILTER" but I don't know a way to condense the duplicates without doing it manually. I also been wondering where you can find the code for functions like "FIND, REPLACE and ect."? If I could find that I could change the coding for "REMOVE DUPLICATES" to change it for words. But hey I don't really know if that really would work or not. Anything would help.

For example:

```
column1   column2   column3
-----------------------------
   y        A       (nothing) 
   z        B       (nothing) 
   z     (nothing)     I
   x     (nothing)     k
   y     (nothing)     j 
   x        C       (nothing)
```

to this

```
column1   column2   column3
-----------------------------
   y         A         j
   z         B         I
   x         C         k
```

except the letters are words.

[image]

Comment: maybe you could post the image of the worksheet, with data, then we can take it from there

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you could do this with formulas in Excel unless you know what word you are looking for within the cell. You could try either a UDF, or a Regular Expression.

my question and answer with links might get you started:

[StackOverflow: formula to see if a surname is repeated within a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334114/formula-to-see-if-a-surname-is-repeated-within-a-cell-and-output-a-simplified-st)

and maybe:

[VBA Express](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?46140-check-if-a-surname-is-repeated-within-a-cell-and-output-a-simpler-name&p=290337&viewfull=1#post290337)

Once you've posted your Excel worksheet with data we see if I've got it wrong!

Comment: what you posted on StackOverflow: formula to see if a surname is repeated within a cell

is almost the same thing, im working on getting the excel doc up

Comment: i can't post pictures yet so you will need to take from my avatar thing from my profile but off course you can't read it :P

Answer (score 1):

You could use advanced filter to copy unique values from column 1 to a new column.  Then you would use a vlookup formula to get the rest.

Assumptions:

- Row 1 is a header row so actual data starts in row 2
- Column1 is column "A"
- Column2 is column "B"
- Column3 is column "C"
- The new column with the unique values is column "E".

In cell F2 and copied over to G2 and then down as needed:

```
=INDEX(INDEX($B$2:$C$7,0,COLUMNS($E2:E2)),MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$7=$E2)*(INDEX($B$2:$C$7,0,COLUMNS($E2:E2))<>""),),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sheet1 Before:**
[image]

Code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    With Sheet1
        .Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CriteriaRange:=.Range("F1:F2"), CopyToRange:=.Range("K1"), Unique:=True
        .Columns("B:B").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CriteriaRange:=.Range("G1:G2"), CopyToRange:=.Range("L1"), Unique:=True
        .Columns("C:C").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CriteriaRange:=.Range("H1:H2"), CopyToRange:=.Range("M1"), Unique:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

**Sheet1 After:**
[image]

make sure field names are used.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a function that will find the first non-blank cell against a specific string

```
Option Explicit

Function NonBlankLookup(SearchTxt As String, LookIn As Range, OffSetRows As Long) As Variant
Dim loc As Range
Dim FirstFound As Range

Set loc = LookIn.Find(what:=SearchTxt)
While Not (loc Is Nothing)
    If Not IsEmpty(loc.Offset(0, OffSetRows)) Then
        NonBlankLookup = loc.Offset(0, OffSetRows).Value
        Exit Function
    End If
    If FirstFound Is Nothing Then
        Set FirstFound = loc
    ElseIf loc = FirstFound Then
        NonBlankLookup = CVErr(2000)
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set loc = LookIn.Find(what:=SearchTxt, after:=loc)
Wend
NonBlankLookup = CVErr(2000)
End Function
```

to use, insert this code into a module, then in your excel spreadsheet, you can use a formula like `=NonBlankLookup(E1,$A$1:$A$6,1)` which will search for your text in **A1:A6**, and check 1 column to the right. If no text is found that matches the search string, or if the text is found but no data exists in the specified column, **#NULL!** is returned.
This also has a slight advantage to vlookup, as it will allow negative offset, so you could have the search text in column 2, and by using -1 for the offset, you could return data from column 1

Just so you are aware, because of the way that `.find` works, when you specify a range, it will start at the *2nd* cell, and go down, and search the first cell you give it last.
e.g. with my example of **A1:A6**, it will search *A2,A3,A4,A5,A6* and finally *A1*