# Copying of data skipping blanks

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Good Day, can somebody please help me.  I have 2 spreadsheets, the second spreadsheet has got the copied cells exactly like the first one.  But my problem is that on the first spreadsheet I have blank rows as the invoices are being put in date order and not invoices on every day.  The second sheet I use for Vat purposes and want my selection there to be in list form in order to only print 1 page for bookkeeper.  Where I have invoices for eg. on 10th, 15th and 20th on first spreadsheet "what formula can I use for the 3 invoices to appear in the second spreadsheet eg. in row 1,2,3 one right underneath the other one.

I have done VBA 20 years ago and came right with everything except this I can not figure out for the life of me.  Thanks in advance to anybody that can help me with this.

Comment: Look at the advanced filter function. It's similar to my example here which I posted yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164851/is-there-way-to-find-duplicate-words/18166832#18166832

Answer (score 0):

highlight, press F5, click "special" select either "constants" or "formulas" depending on if it is hardcoded or formulaic data, then hit ok. this will leave all blank cells out of the selection, then copy paste as normal to the other workbook. if your doing it in vba this is all available in the object model as

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Select
```

UPDATE: I forgot about the bug (design flaw?) in excel that makes it error out when you try to copy a non-rectangular selection. See here (the article is older but appears to apply to 2013):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100715

I believe there are macros available on the internet to deal with this problem, one of them is here

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/799-excel-copy-multiple-selections.html

A quick fix would be to take the inverse approach: use the "special" selection to select blanks, and then delete them. then select a rectangle around the remaining cells.

the VBA call to select blanks is

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks, 23).Select
```

Comment: Seth, when I try to copy the selected cells, I get an error message saying "That command cannot be used on multiple selections."

Comment: is everything is one column or spread across multiple columns

Comment: Okay. Tried it on a single column and it worked. Might help if you explain that in your answer. Could be a problem for the OP if she does have multiple columns of data in her invoices and not all columns have the same blanks in them.

Comment: Very good point, @chuff. I never understood why this issue is so persistant across versions of excel. seems the core of the issue is excel doesn't know how to shift the cells into a contiguous block to match the intent of the user. why couldn't they adopt a default behavior like "slide everything to the top left" or something?